# How to prevent a input field from `validation`?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a scenario to show details in the input field. I am getting the information from one of the drop-down objects.

When the user selects the drop-down objects, from the object, I would like to bring and show the details in the input field as a text, (even read-only).

But when I bring the description details from the drop down objects to input field, always my form goes as `$invalid`. How to prevent my form to not consider one of the text fields ?

Here is my input field:

I tried using `non-bind` prop. but I am not getting the description details in the input field.

```html
<div class="form-group__text" ng-if="ctrl.data.productDetails">
  <label class="fs-label">&nbsp;</label>
  <input name="itemDescription" class="fs-input-item" type="text" placeholder="Product Description" ng-model="ctrl.itemDesc">
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it seems a lot of strange. There's no way to **this** input be `$invalid` since it even has a validation.

Answer (score 0):

Add formnovalidate="formnovalidate" to any inputs you don't want validated.

```
<input name="itemDescription" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" class="fs-input-item" type="text" placeholder="Product Description" ng-model="ctrl.itemDesc">
```